# Querying for a specific column field in myBatis

Tags: java, database, spring-mybatis

I am trying to create a mybatis query for the below sql query with id and message_type as input parameters

```
SELECT id, outbound_message, outbound_message_date,'ABC' message_type 
FROM DB
WHERE id=1200;
```

I tried the query below but I get a binding error.

```
<select id="findTask" resultMap="taskRow">
    SELECT id, outbound_message, outbound_message_date,'#{process}' message_type 
    FROM DB where id=#{id};
</select>
```

Is there a better way to write the message_type column?

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant way to define what you want is to use a custom `<sql/>` block like this:

```
<sql id="message_type_column">
 '#{process}' message_type
</sql>
```

Therefore, you write your query like this:

```
<select ...>
    SELECT id, 
           outbound_message, 
           outbound_message_date,
           <include refid="message_type_column"/>  
    FROM DB where id=#{id}
</select>
```